# Duplicates when using Left Outer Join to correct values in column that are Row+1

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that looks something like this

Table 1

| LOG_ID | DATE | ROOM | USER | MINUTES | ROOM_IN | ROOM_OUT | TURNAROUND |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 08/01/23 | 1 | DOE, JANE | 50 | 7:35 | 8:30 | 0 |
| 12345 | 08/01/23 | 1 | DOE, JANE | 5 | 7:35 | 8:30 | 0 |
| 67890 | 08/01/23 | 1 | DOE, JOHN | 20 | 9:04 | 9:24 | 34 |
| 12111 | 08/01/23 | 1 | PATEL, NANCY | 28 | 10:52 | 11:20 | 88 |
| 12222 | 08/01/23 | 1 | DREW, AMBER | 100 | 11:41 | 15:21 | 21 |

I've noticed that turnaround time is applied to the log that follows turnaround, rather than to the log that proceeds it.

For example, Log 12345 ended at 8:30 am and Log 67890 started at 9:04 am. The 34 minute turnaround should be applied to Log 12345, not Log 67890 as demonstrated in the table above.

Table 2 looks like this:

| LOG_ID | PRECEDING_LOG_ID | ROOM_OUT_TO_IN |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 67890 | 12345 | 34 |
| 12222 | 12111 | 21 |
| 12111 | 67890 | 88 |

I created the following CTEs

```
CORRECT_TAT AS 
(
    SELECT tb2.PRECEDING_LOG_ID AS PRE_LOG_ID, tb1.TURNAROUND AS CORRECT_ACTUAL_TAT_2
    FROM tb1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tb2 ON tb1.LOG_ID = tb2.LOG_ID
),
CORRECT_TAT_2 AS 
(
    SELECT 
        tb1.*, 
        NVL(CT.CORRECT_ACTUAL_TAT_2, 0) AS CORRECT_ACTUAL_TAT_2,
        NVL(CT.CAPPED_ACTUAL_TAT_2, 0) AS CAPPED_ACTUAL_TAT_2
    FROM
        tb1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        CORRECT_TAT CT ON tb1.LOG_ID = CT.PRE_LOG_ID
)
```

What I hoped for was to create a temp table with tb2.PRECEDING_LOG_ID as the primary key of the table and pull tb1.TURNAROUND.

So, the CTE table would look like:

| PRE_LOG_ID | CORRECT_ACTUAL_TAT_2 |
| --- | --- |
| null | null |
| 12345 | 34 |
| 12111 | 21 |
| 67890 | 88 |

My ideal output:

| LOG_ID | DATE | ROOM | USER | MINUTES | ROOM_IN | ROOM_OUT | TURNAROUND |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 08/01/23 | 1 | DOE, JANE | 50 | 7:35 | 8:30 | 34 |
| 12345 | 08/01/23 | 1 | DOE, JANE | 5 | 7:35 | 8:30 | 0 |
| 67890 | 08/01/23 | 1 | DOE, JOHN | 20 | 9:04 | 9:24 | 88 |
| 12111 | 08/01/23 | 1 | PATEL, NANCY | 28 | 10:52 | 11:20 | 21 |
| 12222 | 08/01/23 | 1 | DREW, AMBER | 100 | 11:41 | 15:21 | 0 |

For duplicate logs (Row 1 & 2), would it be possible to have turnaround applied once? Since, turnaround happens only once.

The issue with my code is it causes duplicates.

For example, Log 67890 appears only once in tb1, but my code produces the following:

| LOG_ID | DATE | ROOM | USER | MINUTES | ROOM_IN | ROOM_OUT | TURNAROUND |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 08/01/23 | 1 | DOE, JANE | 50 | 7:35 | 8:30 | 34 |
| 12345 | 08/01/23 | 1 | DOE, JANE | 5 | 7:35 | 8:30 | 34 |
| 67890 | 08/01/23 | 1 | DOE, JOHN | 20 | 9:04 | 9:24 | 0 |
| 67890 | 08/01/23 | 1 | DOE, JOHN | 20 | 9:04 | 9:24 | 88 |

The number of rows doesn't change with CTE CORRECT_TAT, but I get more rows with CTE CORRECT_TAT_2, so I believe this is where it's going all wrong.

The data is usually not sorted in any way.

I appreciate any help, I tried to make the data as simple as possible.

Comment: Hi - you seem to have duplicate log ids in your data and you talk about times but all your data is just dates not timestamps. Please can you fix/explain these issues?

Comment: @NickW I included the timestamps. There are duplicate log ids in table 1 because the total minutes in the room is broken down into increments. For example, Log 12345 total minutes would be 55 minutes. I am not exactly sure why 55 is broken down as 50 and 5 minutes as different rows. There are multiple cases like this in table 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table already contains the data you want, but the turnaround is not in the row where it belongs, but always in the row following it.

Use `LEAD` to get the next row's data:

```
select
  log_id, date, room, user, minutes, room_in, room_out,
  nvl(lead (turnaround) over (order by room, date, room_in), 0) as turnaround
from tb1
order by room, date, lpad(room_in, 5, '0');
```

If you want to update the rows, you can use this query in a `MERGE` statement:

```
merge into tb1 using
(
  select
    log_id, dt, room, usr, minutes, room_in, room_out,
    nvl(lead(turnaround) over (order by room, dt, lpad(room_in, 5, '0')), 0) as turnaround
  from tb1
) correction on (correction.rowid = tb1.rowid)
when matched then update set tb1.turnaround = correction.turnaround;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/8CnZ0dKi